# Issues consuming a server response using Angular 2 RxJS

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, rxjs

My spa uses Angular 2 and asp.net core web api. I'm attempting to consume a response from a web api controller. Both my Angular components and asp.net controllers are hosted on the same local server. Here's the controller class for the data I'm trying to display:

```
public class SampleDataController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public string[] ShuttleTimes()
    {
        List<DateTime> times = new List<DateTime>();
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime end = new DateTime(2017, 2, 8);

        while(time < end){
            times.Add(time);
            time = time.AddMinutes(20);
        }
        string[] convertedTimes = new string[times.Count];
        string toAdd;
        for (int i = 0; i < times.Count; i++)
        {
            toAdd = times[i].ToString();
            convertedTimes[i] = toAdd;
        }

        return convertedTimes;
    }

}
```

Here's my client-side Service:

```
export class ShuttleService{
private baseUrl: string = '/api/SampleData/ShuttleTimes';
constructor(private http : Http) {}

getShuttleTimes(): Observable<any>{
let shuttle$ = this.http
    .get(this.baseUrl)
    .map(this.mapShuttles)

    return shuttle$;
}

mapShuttles(response: Response): any {
return response.json();
}
}
```

And here's my component that uses the service:

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
futureShuttle: boolean;
shuttleTimes: string[];

constructor(private shuttleService: ShuttleService) {}

setFalse(){
    this.futureShuttle = false;
}

ngOnInit() { this.getShuttles(); }

getShuttles(){
    this.shuttleService.getShuttleTimes()
        .subscribe(shuttles => this.shuttleTimes = shuttles);
}
}
```

**Here's my issue:** My TestComponent member shuttleTimes won't display:

```
<div *ngIf="shuttleTimes">
          {{shuttleTimes[0]}}
          Testing Text
        </div>
```

The "Testing Text" displays, but nothing from shuttleTimes array. What's especially strange is this worked for me just yesterday, and without making any changes I'm aware of, has stopped working. In case it's helpful to know, I used a started kit at https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/ which uses Angular Universal for server-side pre-rendering and also hot module replacement (HMR). I'm very new and don't have any experience with debugging an application like this, so if you could also recommend a debugging tool and tutorial I'd appreciate that.

Comment: I would start by breaking on the server and seeing if the request is being received.

Comment: @chrispy Not sure what you mean. I inspected the page in chrome and under network found this:
Request URL:http://localhost:5000/api/SampleData/ShuttleTimes
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:5000

Also, don't we know that the request was received because *ngIf shows the "Testing Text", which means that shuttleTimes has a non-null value, correct?

Comment: try doing a console.log in your subscription body and see what shuttles is.

Comment: Something like this?
getShuttleTimes(): Observable<any>{
    let shuttle$ = this.http
        .get(this.baseUrl)
        .map(this.mapShuttles)
        .do(x => console.log(x));
       
        return shuttle$;
    }

Comment: I would start with    this.shuttleService.getShuttleTimes()
        .subscribe(shuttles => { console.log(shuttles); this.shuttleTimes = shuttles});

Comment: You need to set a break point at server side, and make sure server response. Error is not obvious, and since we do not the source code, it is hard to say where the error is.